# Wordpress Meta Query when Meta type is object

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a meta user of type object on my custom post type.

Now I would like to query all custom-posts which have this meta value. I have not found a way how to query meta values of type object. Is there a way actually ?

```
 $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'custom-posts',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'user.id',
      'value' => $this->user_id,
    ),
  )
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When WordPress (or a theme or plugin) stores an object or an array as the value of an item of metadata, it first [serializes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the object into a text representation.

For example, this object

```php
$obj = array ('first'=>'Jeff', 'last'=>'Atwood',);
```

when serialized is this text string:

```
a:2:{s:5:"first";s:4:"Jeff";s:4:"last";s:6:"Atwood";}
```

So, if you want to search this item of metadata for, let's say, `Jef`, you'll need something like this:

```php
 $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'custom-posts',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'user.id',
      'value' => 'Jef',
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
  )
);
```

It will search the text of the serialized object for any row that contains the consecutive letters `Jef`. In SQL, it uses  `meta_value LIKE '%Jef%'` to look for the string you're matching.

This is acknowledged by everybody involved with it to be a sloppy and slow kind of search. You *must* check the results it returns to make sure it didn't match the wrong thing. It will match what you do want, but it also may match other things.